What does it mean when someone is drowning and about to eat it? (Read the context)
Before I ask my question I need to clarify some context.
So, I'm now watching anime Parasyte where parasites attack humans and eat their brains in order to take over their bodies. One parasite had attacked a man who then fell into the ocean. The parasite started reaching man's brain, but then thought:

What's happening? It's not breathing. If that doesn't change, the body will die. There's no time to take the brain. Neither one of us will make it. So, since he is about to eat it, I should just go for it and get to merging as fast as I can".

And then it had merged with the man's body but hadn't eaten his brain and saved the man and itself.
I simply don't understand what it is exactly that the man was about to eat? Is it an idiom maybe? But I can't find something about that at all

Whose thoughts are those - the man's or the parasite's ?

I think you mean parasites.

@KateBunting parasite's

"eat it" is slang for "to die" in American English. Not that this necessarily explains that situation. It's not really clear what's going on. Who is "he"?

@TimR that actually explains everything, thanks. I just couldn't find that "eat it" can mean "to die". "He" is the man and those were parasite's thoughts when he was trying to get to man's brain. Thanks again

compare bite the dust and eat dirt (die).

I'd advise against using translated Japanese anime to learn English. There are likely to be things that don't translate well - especially when the specific context involves an unreal sci-fi situation (apparently with intelligent microscopic parasites, in this case! :)
